# php subtracting data

Tags: php, function

I am trying to subract data in php.

I currently have 2 functions which generate 2 different values pulled in from the database.

```
function total_points() { 
    $query = "SELECT userid, SUM(value) FROM wp_scloyalty GROUP BY userid"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['SUM(value)'];
    }
}



function total_prizes_value($author) { 
    global $post;
    $info = get_userdata($author->ID);
    $id = $info->ID;
    $query = "SELECT userid, SUM(prizevalue) FROM wp_scloyalty_orders WHERE userid = '$id' GROUP BY userid"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['SUM(prizevalue)'];
    }
}
```

I would like to subtract the bottom function from the top. How would i go about doing this in another function so i can use it site wide?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo $row['SUM(prizevalue)'];
```

use

```
return $row['SUM(prizevalue)'];
```

this way you can assign the returned value from your functions to a new variable, and do whatever you want with that (for instance, calculations, or echo it) like this:

```
$newvar = total_prizes_value($author);
$newvar = $newvar + 5;

echo $newvar;
```

(will echo the result that your function would otherwise echo + 5)

Comment: when changing it to return, the result is then null?

Comment: No, changing it to return instead of echo will return the value of your query to the new variable instead of sending it to the screen. I edited my answer to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$answer = total_prizes_value($author) - total_points();
```

Simply `echo $answer,` but use return statement instead of echo